# Can't build angular-dart to js

Tags: dart, angular-dart

By following Angular-Dart tutorial [Chapter 07](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/tree/master/Chapter_07) I get:

```
 'Scope' doesn't implement 'containsValue'.
```

It dosin't build...

For the record I did :

```
dart -c bin/generator.dart
```

It may have to do with Dart update, but I am not sure. 
I am using a Windows 7 x64, Dart 1.1.1, Angular-Dart 0.9.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chapter 7 is currently broken. Track https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/issues/35

Comment: Any ideas how could I build Angular Dart project to js? Are there any other build's that work?

Comment: dart2js build should work (if you're not using the generators). BTW, the issues were fixed and expected to be included in 0.9.5 release.